# Updating Reminder table with the date passed(ManualEntry)

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, datetime-format

```
      --Parameters---
       @InstrumentID VARCHAR(MAX),
       @ReminderSentDate datetime,
       @Return INT OUTPUT

--=========================================================================================    ===

     AS

   BEGIN

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        --===============================UPDATE LAST REMINDER SENT=======================================

       DECLARE @Reminder VARCHAR(MAX)


     SET @Reminder = 'UPDATE InstrumentReminderSent SET ReminderSentDate=@ReminderSentDate WHERE InstrumentID in (' + @InstrumentID + ')'

   EXEC(@Reminder)

SET @Return=@@ROWCOUNT

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This is SP If I execute this giving values of InstrumentID=7 and ReminderSentDate ='2014-02-28' I'm getting Error as "Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@ReminderSentDate"."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a scope issue. Have you tried making the @ReminderSentDate dynamic in the update statement?

SET @Reminder = 'UPDATE InstrumentReminderSent SET ReminderSentDate=' + @ReminderSentDate + ' WHERE InstrumentID in (' + @InstrumentID + ')'